# What belongs in the "Work Experience" section of graduate applications - is undergraduate research experience included?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, research-undergraduate

Nearly every graduate school application has this section for Work Experience. Are things such as REUs (Research Experience for Undergraduates) considered work? Or is this meant for work that isn't directly research experience?

Comment: ...and REUs stands for....?

Comment: @Nicholas: [Research Experiences for Undergraduates](http://www.nsf.gov/funding/pgm_summ.jsp?pims_id=5517&from=fund)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work experience normally refers to internships or part-time jobs you've done with companies besides your university, or actual employment positions in your university such as working in the library or grading papers. Research experience is related to academics, so it should be treated as such. I know you get paid for it, but it's used to augment your undergraduate experience and thus adds value to your degree.